# How to use a loop in this case?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I have 3 matrices,

```
test_1=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15; 16 17 18];
test_2=[16 18 15; 6 5 8; 2 9 5; 11 19 21; 22 28 30; 14 16 19];
test_3=[11 9 7; 8 22 17; 27 31 30; 28 26 40; 66 57 36; 82 21 19];
```

I want to save all the elements of first two rows as,

```
firstrow_test_1= test_1([1; 2],:);
firstrow_test_2= test_2([1; 2],:);
firstrow_test_3= test_3([1; 2],:);
```

These matrices will give the result of all the elements of first two rows of test_1,test_2,test_3. 
Then I want to take the 3rd and 4th row of test_1,test_2 and test_3 and save the elements in another set of metrices.

```
secondrow_test_1= test_1([3; 4],:);
secondrow_test_2= test_2([3; 4],:);
secondrow_test_3= test_3([3; 4],:);
```

Similarly for the rest, I have to do,

```
thirdrow_test_1= test_1([5; 6],:);
thirdrow_test_2= test_2([5; 6],:);
thirdrow_test_3= test_3([5; 6],:);
```

If I do this way then the code will be very long. So is there any way to write the code in a shorter way? Can anybody please help me to use a loop in this case,if it is possible?

2. What if we have 50 matrices like test_1,test_2,...,test_50 and we want to do the same in that case? (save the first 2 rows in another matrix,then the next 2 rows in another matrix..etc)

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you really need to do this? why do you need to extract these two rows at all? do you need to pass them to a specific function which expects that input format?

Comment: Yes I believe I have to do this. I am currently working on a finger printing method where I am using 3 receivers with one transmitters and I am also considering different direction of emissions. I am doing an analysis from a set of codes and each time I am getting all the RSSI values from 3 receivers in one file for each point. So I want to separate those values by using this strategy. Is there any way to solve it out?

Answer (score 1):

This is MatLab (Matrix Laboratory). you need to make use of multiple dimensions of a matrix to store the data instead of creating separate variables, if they all are of same dimensions (as in your case). Else if their dimensions are not same, you could use cell arrays.

Here are some links which might help you.

- [Multidimensional Arrays](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html)
- [Cell Arrays](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Taking your example (see how easily you could solve your problem with use of nD matrices)

```
%// creating multidimensional matrix from those 2D matrix
A = cat(3,test_1, test_2, test_3);   %// stacking each 2D slices in 3rd dimension
```

for example,
`firstrow_test_1` could be accessed by using `A(1:2,:,1)`.

Similarly,
`firstrow_test_2` could be accessed by using `A(1:2,:,2)`

and so on.. I hope you got an idea.

Here i created a 3D matrix from the 2D slices as you had them as 2D slices. But you should be able to create 3D matrices directly and the same process could be applied.